# How to asynchronously define javascript object property

Tags: javascript, object, asynchronous

Can someone help me define an object property asynchronously? My example below returns `name : undefined and I can't find any strategies on how to do this synchronously...

```
function returnName () {
    setTimeout(function() { 
    return 'John Wick'
  }, 3000);
}

const person = {
    name: returnName(),
  age: 23
}

console.log(person) // person.name returns `undefined`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "return value" from a timeout is the ID of that timeout...

Comment: Why don't you wait 3 seconds and then assign the property to the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to use something like a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to set/log the name of the `person` only once the name has resolved from function `returnName()` whether that's through a `setTimeout()` or an async DB call? A `Promise` would give you a simple, effective way to only execute an action once the async method has completed and provides you options for handling successes and errors via `.then()` and `.catch()`.

```
function returnName() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return resolve('John Wick');
    }, 3000);
  });
}

let person = { age: 23 };

returnName().then(function(name) {
  person.name = name;
  console.log(person);
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvy6b4cL/4/) demonstrating the functionality.

Hopefully this helps!